# Ansible postgresql_table: how to create a foreign key constraint?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

Creating databases and tables using the postgresql module in Ansible is pretty straight forward and works great, but I can´t really figure out how to create a foreign key constraint.

Eg. I create a table in Ansible like this:

```
    - name: "Create foo table"
      become: yes    
      become_user: postgres
      community.postgresql.postgresql_table:
        db: test_db
        owner: postgres
        name: foo
        columns:
          - id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
          - bar_id bigint
```

Now I would like to create a foreign key constraint that references the `id` column in the table `bar`. In Postgresql I could add a foreign key constrain this like this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT bar_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar (id) MATCH FULL;
```

How can this be done in Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a foreign key constraint *when you create the table* by adding a `CONSTRAINT` to the columns list, like this:

```
    - name: "Create foo table"
      become: yes    
      become_user: postgres
      community.postgresql.postgresql_table:
        db: test_db
        owner: postgres
        name: foo
        columns:
          - id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
          - bar_id bigint
          - CONSTRAINT bar_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar (id) MATCH FULL;
```

Or just include the constraint in the column definition:

```
    - name: "Create foo table"
      become: yes    
      become_user: postgres
      community.postgresql.postgresql_table:
        db: test_db
        owner: postgres
        name: foo
        columns:
          - id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
          - bar_id bigint REFERENCES bar(id) MATCH FULL
```

But you **cannot** add a constraint after the fact using the
`postgresql_table` module: it doesn't support the use of `ALTER TABLE`
to synchronize the database table with changes in your playbook.

From the documentation, the `postgresql_table` module can be used to
"change some table attributes", but looking at the source that appears
to be limited to:

- Renaming the table
- Changing the table owner
- Changing the tablespace
- Changing store parameters

Comment: Works like a charm - thx mate !!! This should go into the documentation :)